# Excel VBA to transfer records to Access table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm new to this forum and I'm hoping someone out there can help me out.  I'll attach the code I'm using for reference, which by the way has always worked for me.

I'm using Excel vba to transfer data from Excel into an Access table.  For some reason, the code seems to run perfectly up until "With rs", then it seems to skip adding the values and goes directly to rs.Close.  I don't receive any error messages either, which is strange to me. A Sample of the code is included.

If anyone has some suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long

'ESTABLISH DATABASE AND TABLE LOCATION - PRODUCTION
'Prod environment location
'Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\!PITF Docs\Forecasting and Planning\Collection\PITF_Collection.accdb")
' open the database
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\!PITF Docs\Forecasting and Planning\Collection\PITF_Collection.accdb")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Upload_InternalLabor", dbOpenTable)

' get all records in a table
r = 2 ' the start row in the worksheet
Do While Abs(Range("HZ" & r)) > 0
' repeat until first empty cell in column A
    With rs
        .AddNew ' create a new record
        ' add values to each field in the record
        .Fields("Class") = Range("DO" & r).Value
        .Fields("New_Hire") = Range("DP" & r).Value
        .Fields("Name") = Range("DQ" & r).Value
        .Fields("Role") = Range("DR" & r).Value
        .Fields("Expense_Driver") = Range("DS" & r).Value
        .Fields("Comments") = Range("DT" & r).Value
        .Fields("Salary") = Range("DU" & r).Value
        .Fields("Hire_Date") = Range("DV" & r).Value
        .Fields("42741") = Range("DW" & r).Value
        .Fields("42755") = Range("DX" & r).Value
        .Fields("42769") = Range("DY" & r).Value
        .Fields("42783") = Range("DZ" & r).Value

        .Fields("Submitter") = Range("HW" & r).Value
        .Fields("Timestamp") = Range("HX" & r).Value
        .Fields("Total") = Range("HY" & r).Value
        .Fields("Abs") = Range("HZ" & r).Value


        ' add more fields if necessary...
        .Update ' stores the new record
    End With
    r = r + 1 ' next row
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I suspect that you loop isn't looping. Can you toss a breakpoint on `With rs` (Click on the line and hit F9), run the procedure, and see if it breaks on that line. If it doesn't then your loop condition is failing `Abs(Range("HZ2")) > 0`

Comment: Are you using DAO ? Then I would specify `Dim db as DAO.Database`, same for `rs`. Also, Try `dbOpenDynaset` instead of `dbOpenTable`

Comment: Hmm...it doesn't appear to break...just continues to Set rs = Nothing. (I stepped through it using F8).  Any suggestions on how to fix?  Like I mentioned before, I've used this code for several other worksheets and have never had a problem.  Thanks so much

Comment: Take a look at cell `HZ2` and see why it's not greater than 0 like the loop requires. I have no idea what that means in the context of your workbook or code, but that's definitely the culprit. This code is starting at Row 2 and insrerting data. Perhaps your data starts on a different row now and you need to change `r=2` to whatever that row is? Just guessing here.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these are working.  I'm not using DAO because I'm using excel 2016.  The code works perfectly in another file I have, and I haven't done anything different in this one with the exception of changing the database name/location/table, etc, and the field names.

Comment: Using `Range("HZ2")` is equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Range("HZ2")`. Make sure that the required sheet is active before running the macro or, better still, specify the actual worksheet in the code

Comment: OMG! I'm so stupid.  That worked perfectly, the code was just out of order so the worksheet was re-hidden, therefore not active.  I switched it around and now it works perfectly.  Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your tables are setup in the same column order you can literally copy/paste them in if it's only a 1-time thing.

If it is not a one time thing, but still an Access database, you can link the excel file via the `External Data` section and then do an `UPDATE` or `APPEND` query based on some key that's in both tables.

1. Select the `File name` in the wizard
2. Select the `Link to the data source by creating a linked table` radio button
3. Click `OK`

Once you have the `Excel` file linked you can treat it just like any other table.

Comment: Unfortunately this file will be a working document, so it's not a one time thing.  Thank you though.